# Odd and confusing PHP syntax

Tags: php

I am taking over the maintenance of an old web site and came across this confusing syntax for processing a form that I have never seen before, and I am not exactly certain what it does:

```
foreach (array('address','comments','country','email','mail_content','name','title') as $vuln) 
{
    isset($_REQUEST[$vuln]) and $_REQUEST[$vuln] = htmlentities($_REQUEST[$vuln]);
    isset($_GET[$vuln]) and $_GET[$vuln] = htmlentities($_GET[$vuln]);
    isset($_POST[$vuln]) and $_POST[$vuln] = htmlentities($_POST[$vuln]);
    isset($$vuln) and $$vuln = htmlentities($$vuln);
}
```

It's the "and" that is throwing me - I read it as "if variable is set convert it to htmlentities, but why is there an "and" in there?

Finally what does the last line do?

```
isset($$vuln) and $$vuln = htmlentities($$vuln);
```

Comment: I don't know why the devloper is using `REQUEST`, `GET`, and `POST`. The `$$vuln` is a variable variable. http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Comment: Thanks everyone for the quick and informative answers - would love to accept all your answers but can't...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's using the [operator precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php) rules of PHP in an unusual way.

If you have an `and` statement, PHP will stop processing it if the left side is false - there's no need to check the right hand side, because it won't make a difference to the end result. (The converse is also true for an `or` statement if the left hand side is true.)

So the coder that wrote this is using it as a shorthand for:

```
if (isset($_REQUEST[$vuln])) {
    $_REQUEST[$vuln] = htmlentities($_REQUEST[$vuln]);
}
```

They've save a small amount of typing, at the cost of making the code slightly harder to read. It's good practice to use `isset` to make sure that your array values are set before you use them, which is why the check is there.

As to the last line; logically, it's doing the same as the above, but with a [variable variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php). The first time through, `$vuln` will be set to the first item in your array, which is `address` - the final line of code is checking to see if there's a variable called `$address`, and if so, set its value to `htmlentities($address)`.

That's what the code is doing. *Why* it's checking REQUEST, GET, and POST is beyond me.

Answer (score 2):

```
isset($var) and <statement goes here that uses $var>;
```

This basically only executes the `<statement ...>` if the statement preceding `and` (in this case `isset($var)`) evaluates to `true`. This happens because if anything is false before a `and`, there's no need to evaluate (or execute) the rest. This works similarly to:

```
if (false && condition) { ... }
```

The `condition` will never be evaluated, since no matter what its value evaluates to, the if condition will always evaluate to `false`.

A more readable alternative for the first example:

```
if (isset($var)) {
   <statement goes here that uses $var>;
}
```

As pointed out in the comments by @chris85, see [$$variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

An example of a variable variable:

```
$vuln = 'abc';  /* Regular variable assignment */
$$vuln = 'def'; /* This is "equivalent" to $abc = 'def'
                 * because $$vuln expands to $<contents of $vuln>,
                 * therefore $abc is assigned with 'def'.
                 */

/* $abc is now a variable with 'def' as its value */
```

Answer (score 2):

Hi These are the nothing but the shortend form.

```
 isset($_REQUEST[$vuln]) and $_REQUEST[$vuln] = htmlentities($_REQUEST[$vuln]);
```

above line means

```
if(isset($_REQUEST[$vuln])){
$_REQUEST[$vuln] = htmlentities($_REQUEST[$vuln]);
}
```

Also the `$$vuln` is a `reference` `variable` its checking the same that if reference `variable` is set then assign it value

Answer (score 2):

It might be easier to comprehend as the following, for the first iteration through the array:

```
<?php

if(isset($_REQUEST['address'])) {
    $_REQUEST['address'] = htmlentities($_REQUEST['address']);
}
if(isset($_GET['address'])) {
    $_GET['address'] = htmlentities($_GET['address']);
}
if(isset($_POST['address'])) {
    $_POST['address'] = htmlentities($_POST['address']);
}
if(isset($address)) {
    $address = htmlentities($address);
}
```

It looks to me like legacy code that probably was a replacement for (or perhaps in addition to) 'magic quoting' when 'register globals' was turned on.  Probably so they could do some pseudo escaping of variables before database inserts and or page echos.